# Yevamot Relationship Chart

Tags: marriage, internet, talmud-bavli, masechet-yevamot

I remember seeing a Web 1.0ish website with a great chart with ALL of the relationships described in Mesechet Yevamot. This website also had a click through tour of diagrams of the Beit Hamikdash. I believe that it is someone's personal web site (i.e. it has some of their research on it too.) Does anyone know which website I'm remembering? I am going to start Yevamot soon, and it would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is about 5 years too late, but maybe it will help someone else.

[Daf Hachaim](https://dafhachaim.org/) has many charts organized by Daf, and has charts for many cases in Yevamos.